# Explaining the phrase なかなか片{かた}付{づ}かない

Tags: grammar, syntax

なかなか片{かた}付{づ}かない means "hard to clean up". My question is ～か～ part in this sentence. The verb is 片付ける, but what 片付**か** is doing here?

Comment: I recommend you look up the intransitive [片付]{かたづ}く, not the transitive [片付]{かたづ}ける.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

片付く is intransitive and 片付ける is transitive, so they conjugate differently.

片付か is 未然形(nai form) of 片付く. And 片付く has some meaning, for example,　仕事が片付く(Works finish), 私の部屋は片付いている(My room is in good order.).